# How to add Json keys to an array list in Django REST framework

Tags: json, django, rest

I'm using Django REST framework to make an API.

For my serialized models I get a response looks like this:

[GET] http://12.0.0.1/0.5/barrios/?format=json

```
[
  {
    "name": "La Julia",
    "zone": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "La Floresta",
    "zone": 2
  }
]
```

But, what I want looks like this:

```
{
  "barrios": { 
    "barrio": [
      {
        "name": "La Julia",
        "zone": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "La Floresta",
        "zone": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `list()` method in your view to get the desired response.

```
class MyView(..):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        serializer_data = serializer.data # get the default serialized representation
        custom_data = {'barrios': {'barrio': serializer_data}} # custom representation
        return Response(custom_data)
```